# How can I find out which page links to a given URL?

Tags: url, google-search

I have an URL, say this web page: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-12-Basel/Keynote-The-great-8-Windows-and-Windows-Phone

**How can I find out which other pages on the internet link to this page?** Probably Google can help, but how?

Would it also work if the URL in question is not a page, but a (media) file, say this one: http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/f75a/2507bd0a-9a46-41f8-b8bd-3a0a80f1f75a/TD12BA1_high.mp4
The expected result in this case would be the first URL at least and probably other pages on the net.

EDIT: I'm adding some context on my motivation. What I really want, is not finding all linking pages, but actually, hopefully, the one that is most likely the one of the "owner" of the page in question, the one who created it. For example the writer of that blog post, the copyright holder of that media file etc...

Comment: You can not. With some luck a spider will have mapped all pages linking to it, but you really want **all** webpages, and all right now. Nobody has that information.

Comment: @Hennes: This is obviously not true. All of the big search engines provide a way to see links _to_ a particular URL.

Comment: I disagree. They provide links to a subset of what links to them. Not to *all* of them.  Example: I can create a link to them on my homepage (which is behind a robot.txt) and you will never know. Hence my highlighting **all** in the answer. For a subset the answer from from @week might work well enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [advanced search from google](http://www.google.com/advanced_search), It's nice and easy click and search interface for our uncle Google.

Or use query like this `link:yourlinkedsite.com` as described in [FAQ Google](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=adv_sitespecific&answer=1734233)

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I have changed the links to english content. Although I personally like the czech language much, me and many others will be more comfortable with english :-)

Comment: Hm:(, another attempt to enforce czech in Stack-exchange failed. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the Google Webmaster tools will show a lot more detail (and links), but you need to be able to prove the site is controlled by you.